# Challenges with Activating Livepatch on Ubuntu Pro 22.04.3 LTS Using Kernel linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Hello Ask Ubuntu Community,

I am encountering an issue with enabling Livepatch on my system `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS` running Ubuntu Pro. Despite having the latest version of the kernel, **`linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04`** (version **`6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8`**), Livepatch refuses to activate, and I receive an error message stating, "Could not enable Livepatch. Please try again."

I have confirmed that my subscription to Ubuntu Pro is active and in good standing, as indicated by the enabled Ubuntu Pro support, and the system is up-to-date with all the latest patches installed.

I would appreciate guidance on the following points:

1. Are there any known compatibility issues with the **`linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04`** kernel and Livepatch?
2. Could there be specific system settings or configurations that prevent Livepatch from being enabled?
3. Is there a particular log file or command output that would be useful for diagnosing this problem?

Any help or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance.

[image: Ubuntu Pro]

Comment: The HWE kernel line has just bumped to 6.5 in January 2024, but the [Livepatch reference](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels) is still saying HWE 6.2. Maybe there's a short delay in when Livepatch becomes available for the HWE 6.5 kernel line?