# Why does LivePatch fail this morning after normal updates gave me new kernel?

Tags: kernel, updates, canonical-livepatch

Running **Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS**.

I noticed that LivePatch suddenly failed this morning with the error:

> "An error occurred when checking for LivePatch updates."

I searched around and discovered I could [get the status of LivePatch](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/how-to/status) with the following command-line:

```
$ canonical-livepatch status
```

It reports the following:

**last check**: 11 minutes ago
**kernel**: 6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1-generic

**server check-in**: failed: livepatch check failed: error response with status 502 (Bad Gateway): `"<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>\nThe server returned an invalid or incomplete response.\n</body></html>\n\n"`

**kernel state**: ✗ kernel is not covered by Livepatch

**patch state**: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1-generic

**tier**: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)

**machine id**: [redacted]

**Other Things I Tried**
I attempted to turn off the "Kernel LivePatch" so I could try to turn it on again to see if that would fix it but I got an error (shown in image) there too.

[image: LivePatch settings]

Right after I disabled LivePatch I tried to enable it again and that caused an error too, so it's in an unknown state:

[image: LivePatch unknown state]

I **have not updated the kernel myself**.

Is there some issue where the update system is out of sync or something?

Why is this problem with LiveUpdate occurring?

Is this happening for other people?

Comment: As asked about here frequently, there seems to be a time lag between stepping up to a new HWE kernel series and it working in livepatch. Your question is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1502055/243321

Comment: It looks like Canonical is having an issue with every other Kernel release through the HWE Kernels.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1395863/231142 where I show that 5.15 is covered, but 5.19 is not covered.  6.2 is covered and now it appears as 6.5 is not covered.  My guess is that the next Kernel release with 24.04 LTS will be covered again.  I have filed bugs in the past, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks, that is great info.  At least now I have some idea why this suddenly occurred.  

Answer (score 3):

There's an outage of some services hosted by Canonical.

https://status.snapcraft.io/

[image: Screenshot of snapcraft status page]

https://ubuntu.social/@launchpadstatus/111879418793860513

[image: Screenshot of launchpad status at ubuntu social]

Comment: Thanks for the great info.  I will keep that link so I can check the status for myself.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2024-02-15:**  It appears that `livepatch` is now supporting the 6.5 Kernels.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 8 minutes ago
kernel: 6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1-generic
server check-in: succeeded
kernel state: ✓ kernel series 6.5 is covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 6.5.0-18.18~22.04.1-generic
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
machine id: <redacted>
```

---

I was able to download and install `canonical-livepatch` version 10.8.1 this morning by running `sudo snap refresh`.

```
$ canonical-livepatch --version
canonical-livepatch version 10.8.1
```

Livepatch is now showing that it is working, but it is still showing that the 6.5.0-15-generic Kernel is still not supported.

[image]

[image]

```
$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 6 seconds ago
kernel: 6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1-generic
server check-in: succeeded
kernel state: ✗ kernel is not covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1-generic
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
machine id: <redacted>
```

However, as I have noticed through [Livepatch -- plans to support official HWE kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395799/livepatch-plans-to-support-official-hwe-kernels/1395863#1395863) that it seems that Canonical is only supporting every other HWE Kernel as it comes in.  The new Kernel version of 6.8 that is slated for 24.04 when it is released will probably be covered.